# Evaluate the following Determinant of $12$th degree polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-polynomials

Evaluate $$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{1}{(a+x)^2} & \frac{1}{(b+x)^2} & \frac{1}{(c+x^2)}\\ 
\frac{1}{(a+y)^2} & \frac{1}{(b+y)^2} & \frac{1}{(c+y)^2}\\ 
\frac{1}{(a+z)^2} & \frac{1}{(b+z)^2} & \frac{1}{(c+z)^2}\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

My Try: I have taken all the denominators out and we obtain

$$\Delta=f(a,b,c,x,y,z)\times \begin{vmatrix}
(b+x)^2(c+x)^2 & (a+x)^2(c+x)^2 & (a+x)^2(b+x)^2\\ 
 (b+y)^2(c+y)^2 & (a+y)^2(c+y)^2 & (a+y)^2(b+y)^2\\ 
 (b+z)^2(c+z)^2 & (a+z)^2(c+z)^2 & (a+z)^2(b+z)^2\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$  where

$$f(a,b,c,x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\left((a+x)(b+x)(c+x)(a+y)(b+y)(c+y)(a+z)(b+z)(c+z)\right)^2} $$

By factor theorem we observe that $a-b$,$b-c$,$c-a$,$x-y$,$y-z$ and $z-x$ are factors of the new Determinant above.

But how to find remaining factors?

Comment: Little typo (I think...) for the northeastern entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that we have a factor $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$

Comment: yes but the determinant which is multiplied with $f(a,b,c,x,y,z)$ is of $12$th degree right. So with the above factors we get only $6$th degree. What about the other $6$th degree expression?

Comment: @Ekaveera Kumar Sharma The rest should be something like this: $\sum\limits_{0\leq i,j,k,m,n,l\leq2}a^ib^jc^kx^my^nz^l$, where $i+j+k+m+n+l=6$.